# Async method is not behaving asynchronously

Tags: java, asynchronous

I have written method which takes more time than I desire. It depends on external systems for response so it is slow. I don't have much control over that. Because of that method I cannot wait for that period of time, so my requirement is that after I initialize that method and provided the parameters required it should run in background while the parent method which has called this time consuming method will finish it's execution.

I have used @Async annotation of spring to declare the method as asynchronous. This particular method is being called from RestController which will finish it's execution before this Asynchronous method will finish it's execution.
I have declared custom executor and has mapped it in dispatcher-servlet.xml.

The method is executing asynchronously but the moment caller method finishes it's execution, even though asynchronous method is still incomplete, stops executing abruptly.How can I achieve that the asynchronous method finishes it's execution even though caller method finishes earlier. I cannot wait in caller method for asynchronous method to finish it's execution.

Code Sample
   @Service
    class TimeConsumingService{

```
@Async("customExecutor")
    public  void  callTimeConsumingService( ){

//This call takes time between 50000 miliseconds to 70000 miliseconds
} 

}

//Caller Method

@RestController
@RequestMapping("rest/document/content")
public class CallerController
{

@Autowired
TimeConsumingService timeConsumingService;


 @LoggingAdvice
    @RequestMapping(value="/request", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public String requestContent( @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception, IOException
    {

timeConsumingService.callTimeConsumingService();

}
}
```

Comment: Would be better to provide a minimum, reproducible example so that the folks here can help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you are using spring-boot, are you using the @EnableAsync in your Application? This is what makes the Async annotation works.

Comment: No it's not spring boot, but i can use @EnableAsync for spring too. Method is running asynchronously, but the moment caller method finshes it is also forcing asynchronous method to stop it's execution. That is issue.

Comment: Do you want to keep the long method running after returning a response? Then you may wan to run it in your own executor task / thread.  Using @async I believe the Spring framework assumes the caller will wait for completion or use the Future reference

Comment: Future is used in case of Async if i want to confirm Async process is returning something. I don't want to return anything. I just want it to finish it's entire execution.